# Зачем нужен std::invoke?

Tags: c++, c++17

Увидел сейчас, что в 17ом стандарте появилась новая шаблонная функция `std::invoke`. Очень сильно обрадовался, т.к. подумал, что это такой же `invoke` как в *.NET*, но поискав информацию о нём, так до конца и не понял, зачем он нужен. Я так понял, что он делает вызов функторов и лямбд, но чем это отличается от их прямого вызова? Может ли `std::invoke` делать этот вызов в определённом потоке, как это умеет делать его собрат из *.NET*?

Comment: В .NET есть похожий по смыслу [MethodBase.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight вот уж точно ничуть не похожий. Скорее уж метод Invoke у делегатов...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`std::invoke` нужен чтобы унифицированным образом вызвать функторы (в т.ч. лямбды), указатели на функции и указатели на функции-члены классов. 
Последние имеют специфический синтаксис вызова не совпадающий с синтаксисом обычных функторов:

```
(obj->*mem_fn_ptr)( args... );
```

Если вы пишите функцию типа `std::async`, и вам нужно реализовать поддержку всех *callable* объектов, то проще передать их одним пакетом в `invoke`, чем писать отдельную шаблонную реализацию для каждого случая. Такой синтаксический сахар.

Аналога *.NET* `invoke` в стандарте нет, потому что нет циклов обработки сообщений, и соответственно, "послать задачу в поток" невозможно. Воспользуйтесь `std::async`, либо `std::thread`, если нужно просто асинхронное выполнение, либо функциями *WinAPI*, либо функциями вашей оконной библиотеки (*Qt*, *wxWidgets*...), либо организуйте цикл обработки сообщений "вручную", и запихивайте упакованную задачу в соответствующую очередь.

Answer (score 19):

Смысл `std::invoke` в вызове обычных методов и нестатических методов класса в единообразной манере. Это прежде всего полезно при написании шаблонов. Вот например компактный шаблон функции, оборачивающий вызов другой функции:

```
template<typename F, typename V1, typename V2> auto
foo(F f, V1 v1, V2 v2) -> void
{
    ::std::invoke(f, v1, v2);
}
```

Пример использования:

```
inline auto
bar(int v1, int v2) -> void
{
    ::std::cout << v1 << " " << v2 << ::std::endl;
}

class Bar
{
    private: int m_v;

    public: explicit
    Bar(int v): m_v{v} {}

    public: auto
    bar(int v2) -> void
    {
        ::std::cout << m_v << " " << v2 << ::std::endl;
    }
};

int
main()
{
    int v1{12};
    int v2{23};
    foo(&bar, v1, v2); // вызов обычного метода
    Bar b{12};
    foo(&Bar::bar, b, v2); // вызов нестатического метода класса по ссылке
    foo(&Bar::bar, &b, v2); // вызов нестатического метода класса по указателю
}
```

Без использования `::std::invoke` пришлось бы самостоятельно реализовывать варианты для вызова нестатических методов класса:

```
template<typename F, typename V1, typename V2> auto
foo(F f, V1 v1, V2 v2) -> ::std::enable_if_t
<
    not ::std::is_member_function_pointer_v<F>
>
{
    f(v1, v2);
}

template<typename F, typename V1, typename V2> auto
foo(F f, V1 v1, V2 v2) -> ::std::enable_if_t
<
    ::std::is_member_function_pointer_v<F> and not ::std::is_pointer_v<V1>
>
{
    (v1.*f)(v2);
}

template<typename F, typename V1, typename V2> auto
foo(F f, V1 v1, V2 v2) -> ::std::enable_if_t
<
    ::std::is_member_function_pointer_v<F> and ::std::is_pointer_v<V1>
>
{
    (v1->*f)(v2);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

От прямого вызова это отличается тем, что не всё что умеет вызывать `std::invoke`, можно вызвать напрямую.

Упрощенно говоря, вызов `std::invoke(f, arg0, args...)` пытается сделать один из следующих вызовов:

```
(arg0.*f)(args...);
(arg0.get().*f)(args...);
((*arg0).*f)(args...);
arg0.*f
arg0.get().*f;
(*arg0).*f;
f(arg0, args...);
```

Использование `std::invoke` требуется в тех случаях, когда вы пишите обобщенный код, способный работать с любым переданным Callable-объектом.

Что же до вызова функции в фоновом потоке - то для этих целей придумана функция `std::async`.