# Передача параметром указателя на функцию и указателя на функцию-член с экземпляром

Tags: c++

Изучая STL заметил удобную фичу, позволяющую, по необходимости, обрабатывать как функцию, так и функцию-член с экземпляром класса, которому принадлежит данная функция, аля:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    void f() {}
};

int main()
{
    std::once_flag on;
    A a;
    std::call_once(on, &A::f, a);
}
```

Подскажите, каким образом это реализуемо? Что за механизм? В этом как то замешано `std::tuple`? Как изменить класс `A` для возможности использовать такую "перегрузку"? `f(&A::f, a);` or `f(&f);`

В стандарт глядел, но не переварил(. Не откажусь от литературы по этому поводу.

Comment: Литература - свежий [Вандевурд, Джосаттис и Грегор, "Шаблоны С++".](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-9500296-8-4.html)

Comment: [Зачем нужен std::invoke?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/848165/272035)

Comment: Скорее всего там просто две перегрузки, одна из которых принимает `void (T::*fn)(), T obj`