# Передача разных типов параметров в одну функцию

Tags: c++, c

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли в С++ или в Си реализовать передачу параметров разного типа в одну и ту же функцию ?
При этом я имею ввиду не одно название функции к примеру с двумя разными перегрузками и двумя разными реализациями, а именно одну функцию с одной реализацией.

Ну к примеру:

```
int my_func_1(std::string my_string, int my_int)
{
    char* my_char_p = strstr(&my_string[0], ",");

    int my_int = my_char_p - &my_string[0];

    return my_int;
}


int my_func_2(std::wstring my_wstring)
{

    wchar_t* my_wchar_p = wcsstr(&my_wstring[0], L",");

    int my_int = my_wchar_p - &my_wstring[0];

    return my_int;
}
```

.

```
int my_func(int(*my_func_p) (...), ...)
{

    int my_int = my_func_p(...);

    return my_int;
}





int main()
{

    int my_int = my_func(my_func_1, my_string, my_int);

    int my_int = my_func(my_func_2, my_wstring);

}
```

Можно ли в функцию my_func() при ее первом вызове передать указатель на функцию my_func_1, а при втором вызове передать указатель на функцию my_func_2 - при том, что у my_func_1 и my_func_2 - так же разные параметры?

Comment: Вместо `...` вы можете *передавать* что угодно и сколько угодно...

Comment: в целом, при такой формулировке, похоже нужны шаблоны.

Comment: Передать вы можете. Но что вы будете делать с переданным внутри функции? Вы же переданный аргумент собираетесь вызвать. С какими аргументами? У вас должно быть хорошее представление о коде внутри `my_func`, тогда будет иметь смысл обсуждать аргументы разных типов.

Comment: @KoVadim Тогда это по сути будет перегрузка... В смысле существования нескольких разных функций с параметрами разного типа.

Comment: @KoVadim, я изменил код описание. Вот в такой формулировке - шаблоны нужны будут ?

Comment: Как минимум, вызов `int my_int = my_func_p(...);` не работает. Тут вы должны передавать конкретные аргументы. Ваша же переданная функция должна получать какие-то аргументы? В принципе, такое сделать можно... Можно и ногой ухо почесать. Просто - **зачем**?

Comment: я бы делал на шаблонах. Или на итераторах. Но код, который есть внутри функции (как пример) вызывает большие вопросы в адекватности происходящего.

Comment: @KoVadim, этот код просто для примера не более того.

Comment: не пишите даже для примера "такой код". Но может это просто попытка наприсать приложение, которое будет работать нормально как с юникодными, так и с обычными строками (использование TCHAR и подобного)

Comment: Почитайте про boost::bind - возможно это то, что Вы ищете

Comment: Функция, которая так делает, есть в стандартной библиотеке - `std::invoke`, см https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848131/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-stdinvoke/848165#848165