# Шаблонная функция - недопустимое использование

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем у меня ошибка в попытке сделать шаблонную функцию ?

```
int my_func_1(std::wstring my_wstring, int my_int)
{
    std::cout << "my_wstring_size:" << my_wstring.size();
}

int my_func_2(std::string my_string, int my_int)
{
    std::cout << "my_string_size:" << my_string.size();
}
```

.

```
template <typename my_type1, typename my_type2, typename my_type3, typename my_type4>

int my_func_shablon(int(*pointer_to_func) (my_type1, my_type2), my_type3, my_type4)
{
    pointer_to_func(my_type3, my_type4);  //ОШИБКА: my_type3 : недопустимое использование этого типа в качестве выражения
}
```

.

```
int main()
{
    std::string my_string = "string";

    my_func_shablon(my_func_1, my_string, 1);
}
```

Ошибка:

> my_type3, my_type4 : недопустимое использование этого типа в качестве
> выражения

..

..

..

..

..

Очень условно-абстрактный код:

```
int My_find_substrings_in_string_memcmp_1(std::string& my_string, std::string& my_substring, size_t pos_1, size_t  pos_2, size_t num_find, int chek_error_flag)
{
//Код ищущий подстроку в строке с помощью memcmp:
//......код

return [номер элемента в my_string с которого найдена подстрока]
}


int My_find_substrings_in_string_memcmp_2(std::string& my_string, std::string& my_substring, char* pos_1, char*  pos_2, size_t num_find, int chek_error_flag)
{
//Код ищущий подстроку в строке с помощью memcmp:
//......код

return [номер элемента в my_string с которого найдена подстрока]
}


int My_find_substrings_in_string_wmemcmp_1(std::wstring& my_wstring, std::wstring& my_subwstring, size_t pos_1, size_t  pos_2, size_t num_find, int chek_error_flag)
{
//Код ищущий подстроку в строке с помощью wmemcmp:
//......код

return [номер элемента в my_string с которого найдена подстрока]
}


int My_find_substrings_in_string_wmemcmp_2(std::wstring& my_wstring, std::wstring& my_subwstring, wchar_t* pos_1, wchar_t*  pos_2, size_t num_find, int chek_error_flag)
{
//Код ищущий подстроку в строке с помощью wmemcmp:
//......код

return [номер элемента в my_string с которого найдена подстрока]
}
```

А теперь предположим я хочу добавить функционал подсчета подстрок в строке - мне придется создавать новые 4 -функции и добавлять в них дополнительный код, который будет подсчитывать кол-во найденных подстрок в строке.

Или я могу сделать Одну шаблонную функцию, которая примет на вход указатель на одну из четырех функций и дополнительный параметр в который поместить подсчитанное кол-во подстрок:

```
template <typename my_type1, ... my_type6>

void My_shablon_counting(int(*my_pointer_to_func) (my_type1, ...my_type6), my_type1, ...my_type6, size_t& num_count)
{

repeat:
int result = my_pointer_to_func(my_type1, ...my_type6)

if(result != -1)
{
num_count++;

goto repeat;
}


}
```

.

```
in main()
{
My_shablon_counting(My_find_substrings_in_string_memcmp_1, num_count);
My_shablon_counting(My_find_substrings_in_string_memcmp_2, num_count);
My_shablon_counting(My_find_substrings_in_string_wmemcmp_1, num_count);
My_shablon_counting(My_find_substrings_in_string_wmemcmp_2, num_count);

//То есть вызов функции My_shablon_counting и реализация функции My_shablon_counting - одна, а не 4-е.
}
```

Comment: Функция, которая так делает, есть в стандартной библиотеке - std::invoke, см https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848131/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-stdinvoke/848165#848165 Ну а тут проблема тривиальная - попытка передавать имена типов `my_type3` как аргументы (которые тут оставлены без имен).

Comment: @Harry, ну к примеру, чтобы можно было вызвать только одну функцию, а не две, или три или четыре. Или все такие что то не так ?

Comment: Я просто для начала хотел бы вообще запустить такой код. Пока он вообще не запускается. Насчет ptr_func(a,b) - а если таких функций будет 5 к примеру ? И от этих 5 функций зависит другая функция. Другую функцию придется тоже делать 5 разных реализацией зависящих от ptr_func(a,b) ?

Comment: @Harry, ну все верно вызываю явно. Еще раз, предположим у меня есть функция работа которой зависит от результата выданного my_func_1...my_func_20. Если я не буду использовать шаблоны, то мне вручную явно придется реализовывать все эти 20 my_func, так как [условно] все эти 20 функций принимают разные типи аргументов. А так это сделает за мня компилятор. Шаблоны же для этого и предназначены ?

Comment: @Harry, ну все верно, первоначально у меня есть эти 20 функций реализованный вручную. НО теперь мне нужная функция с дополнительным функционалом, которая будет работать в зависимости от результата одной из этих 20-ти функций. И вот тут именно в этой функции я и применяю шаблоны, передавая в эту функцию указатель на одну из 20 реализованных вручную функций - ИНАЧЕ бы мне пришло делать еще 20 функций - каждая из которых бы вручную ссылалась бы на одну из 20-ти первоначальных функций.

Comment: @Harry, наоборот - я ХОЧУ понять. Но не могу понять, что Вы пытаетесь до меня донести.

Comment: @Harry, я добавил в описаение.

Comment: @Harry, прошу прощения, добавил шаблонную функцию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По моим догадкам вам нужно это:

```
template <typename my_type1, typename my_type2>    
int my_func_shablon(int(*pointer_to_func) (my_type1, my_type2), my_type1 arg3, my_type2 arg4)
{
   return  pointer_to_func(arg3, arg4); 
}
int main() {

    std::string my_string = "string";
    my_func_shablon(my_func_2, my_string, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

И вы хотите знать почему ваш код ошибочный. Шаблон принимает в аргумент указатель на функцию, аргументы которой имеют типы `my_type1` и `my_type2`. И вы пытаетесь вызвать функцию с аргументами других типов и вызываете без объектов(при вызове нужны объекты, а не типы.

При всем этом нужно передавать в функцию соответствующие типы, и вы, к тому же, **не возвращаете ничего** ни из одной функции.

Comment: ага, заработало, Спасибо.